# sha-256 without salt not always returning the same hash

Tags: java, encryption, sha256, sha, jasypt

Can anyone tell me why the following code does not always return the same hash? AFAIK the only way a hash can be different is due to a random salt, but according to the documentation I'm disabling salts by setting the salt size to 0.

```
public static void main(String[] args ) {
    char[] password = "test_pass".toCharArray();
    String str = encodePassword(password);

    System.out.printf(
        "Byte digest '%s'\n", 
        String.valueOf(Hex.encodeHex(Base64.decodeBase64(str)))
    );
}

static StandardByteDigester digester = new StandardByteDigester();
{
    digester.setAlgorithm("SHA-256");
    digester.setIterations(100000);
    digester.setSaltSizeBytes(0);
    digester.initialize();
}

public static String encodePassword(char[] rawPass) {
    return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(digester.digest(toBytes(rawPass))));
}

public static byte[] toBytes(char[] ch) { 
    Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
    ByteBuffer buff = charset.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(ch));
    byte[] tmp = new byte[buff.limit()];
    buff.get(tmp);
    return tmp;    
}
```

Comment: which version of jasypt are you using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bug is related to the fact that you initialize your static field `StandardByteDigester digester` in an **instance initializer block** instead of a **static initializer bloc** such that it is never called as you never create an instance of your class so **at the end it uses the default configuration** with random salt.

**Try this:**

```
static {
    digester.setAlgorithm("SHA-256");
    digester.setIterations(100000);
    digester.setSaltSizeBytes(0);
    digester.initialize();
}
```

---

Your code could be simplified if your method `encodePassword` took a `String` instead of a `char` array as you could simply call `getBytes(Charset)` as next:

```
public static String encodePassword(String rawPass) {
    return new String(
        Base64.encodeBase64(digester.digest(rawPass.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))),
        StandardCharsets.US_ASCII
    );
}
```

**NB:** It is not a good practice to rely on the platform's default charset as your code would then be platform's dependent so here as base 64 characters are all included in `US_ASCII`, let's use this charset to decode.